# How can I mask a domain using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, masking

We have the following situation:

We would like to setup a domain masking to provide content from a project platform to an end user. The end user has setup a `CNAME` record from `player.domain-client.com.` to `app.domainA.com`

Now when the end user enters `https://player.domain-client.com/5432` he should get the contents of `https://app.domainA.com/player/?=5432`.
But the URL should remain `https://player.domain-client.com/5432`.
This masking should only by applied if the client subdomain contains `player`.

Could anybody point me to the right direction on how to setup the `.htaccess` so it does the correct masking?

Comment: you need to use mod_proxy

Comment: I don’t think this needs a reverse proxy - with the CNAME entry in the DNS, the request made to `player.domain-client.com` will go to the correct target web server already. So all the target server has to do now, is respond back with the appropriate content.

Comment: @04FS True, I overlooked that in my haste! (Too many similar questions get asked that _do_ require the reverse proxy.)

Comment: @Ab_lu With the CNAME in place, what happens when you request `https://player.domain-client.com/5432`? Is this the same URL-path that you would request when using the `app.domainA.com` host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The end user has setup a `CNAME` record from `player.domain-client.com.` to `app.domainA.com`

Presumably the "project platform" has also been configured to accept requests to `player.domain-client.com`?

In which case, it should just be a matter of a simple internal rewrite (on the same host). Although, if you would ordinarily request the same URL-path at `app.domainA.com` , ie. `app.domainA.com/5432`, then there is nothing you need to do as the rewrite is already in place? Otherwise, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite any request for /<number> to player/?=<number>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^player\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ player/?=$1 [L]
```

However, `/player/?=5432` isn't the actual endpoint as this requires further rewriting by the system for it to "work". Perhaps you mean something like `/player/index.php?=5432`? (The query string is also a little weird as you are missing a parameter *name*? As written, this would possibly require manual parsing of the query string to extract the value?)

The condition (`RewriteCond` directive) ensures that only requests to the `player` subdomain are rewritten.

On WordPress you need to make sure these directives go *before* the WP front-controller. ie. Before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. The order of directives in `.htaccess` is important.

However, if this is all being managed by WordPress then you can't simply create a rewrite in `.htaccess` since WordPress still sees the original URL that was requested, not the rewritten URL. So, unless the requested URL exists as a valid route in WordPress itself then you'll likely get a 404. This sort of rewrite needs to be managed inside WordPress itself.

#### Alternative solution using a *reverse proxy*

An alternative is to configure your server as a *reverse proxy* and proxy the request from `https://player.domain-client.com/1234` to `https://app.domainA.com/player/?vid=1234` (mentioned in comments). Ideally this requires access to the main server config to config properly (requires mod_proxy and `ProxyPass`, `ProxyPassReverse` directives set appropriate in the virtual host).

Then, in `.htaccess` you would do something like the following instead, making use of the `P` flag on the `RewriteRule`:

```
# Proxy any request for /<number> to player/?=<number>
# for the "player" subdomain only.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^player\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ https://app.domainA.com/player/?vid=$1 [P]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I'm actually on a Wordpress environment. Is there a way to set the rewrite rule so it kicks in only for a specific subdomain (in this case "player.*.*"?

Comment: "I'm actually on a Wordpress environment" - This is the "project platform"? You will need to make sure that these directives come _before_ the WordPress front-controller. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I don't know if I'm on the right track: 
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Rewrite any request for /<number> to player/?=<number>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^player\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ /player/vid?=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: Ideally these directives would go _before_ `# BEGIN WordPress` - near the top of the file. You should avoid manually editing code within the WP code block as WP itself tries to maintain this and could overwrite your custom directives.

Comment: Is the "project platform", that you are trying to rewrite to, actually powered by WordPress? ie. the URL you are rewriting to (`/player/?=5432`) is intended to be routed through WP? (I was assuming it was "outside" of WP and that WP was just for your main site or something?) If it is then this won't work with WordPress unfortunately since WP looks at the requested URL, not the rewritten URL when routing requests. You would need to create these URLs (ie. `/5432`) as routes inside WordPress itself instead, otherwise WP will simply reject them as 404s. (?)

Comment: Yes, it is powered by WP.
We created a page (app.domain.com/player). This page we can access via i.e. https://app.domain.com/player/?vid=1234 and then we get the respective content.
The idea now is to create a rewrite rule so when a client accesses via i.e. https://player.client.com/1234 in the background we get the content https://app.domain.com/player/?vid=1234

But as you mentioned this has to happen via Wordpress itself or maybe using the Redirection plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Yes, I think you will need to configure this route in WordPress itself, not `.htaccess`. Does the "Redirection plugin" handle internal rewrites? Or is this purely for external redirects (which will expose the target URL)? Another alternative is to configure your server as a _reverse proxy_ and proxy the request from `https://player.domain-client.com/1234` to `https://app.domainA.com/player/?vid=1234` - but this may require access to the main server config.

Comment: I was finally able to solve it with your inputs. Had to write a rewrite in Wordpress.